# php-fpm memory consumption

Tags: memory-leaks, nginx, php

I have php5-fpm (with apc) and nginx installed on ubuntu-powered vps server (2000MHz/512MB).
Hosting reported there's abnormal memory consumption on my server. 
`top` shows that there're some php-fpm processes using up to 1gb of memory.

I tried to adjust `pm.max_requests` and `pm.max_children`
but the issue remains.

Any advice will be appreciated greatly.

Here are my configs:

[php.ini](http://pastebin.com/4z8tGQT4) 
[php-conf](http://pastebin.com/q8zZSZb1) 
[nginx.conf](http://pastebin.com/xaLyqtxZ):

Comment: Have you tried using the `ondemand` feature of FPM? Simply change the PM to `pm = ondemand`, restart FPM and then retest and see if this helps any as a test.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the configuration and will keep monitoring the situation to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you have to much server in php-fpm.
you can configure your php-fpm pool server using this below calculator.

Now we can decide how many processes the server is allowed to spin up.

Total Max Processes = (Total Ram - (Used Ram + Buffer)) / (Memory per php process)
This server is has about 512MB of ram. Let's say PHP(your request) uses about 30mb of ram per request.

We can start with: 521 / 30 = 17.06 Let's just go with 17 max servers.
if your request consume 100MB per request then
512/100 = 5.12 so you have to configure 5/4 max server for php-fpm pool.

now your apache/nginx take some ram so i suggest to set 10 server only.

Comment: you can refere  this url also :- https://serversforhackers.com/video/php-fpm-process-management